# How to let Tensorflow to use multipe GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I use Tensorflow to train a model with 3 GPUs. But, I found it uses only 1. The code does not have any GPU configuration, as I thought Tensorflow will automatically detect GPUs and distribute computation into 3 GPUs automatically. It seems not work as I expected.

From attached screenshot, 3 GPUs are detected when training program starts, but temperature monitor shows only 1 is active.

How to use 3 GPUs at same time during training?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XooJw.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will adding GPU cards automatically scale tensorflow usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118918/will-adding-gpu-cards-automatically-scale-tensorflow-usage)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually configure your code to use multiple GPU's for your training.
Because one must define context for every GPU operation and you will have to define the context of the three GPU's you have and divide or assign tasks to be carried out by the respective GPU's manually.
Please refer to the below links, it might help you achieving what you are looking for.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu    (for general GPU configuration)

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn  (this is an example of a CNN training on multiple GPU's)

Comment: I read the sample. But, still not clear how to 'slice' CNN into different pieces so that I can be 'calculated' on different GPUs which is parallel, as the operations are dependent. I image to horizontally slice the CNN into 3 pieces, which can be parallel on 3 GPUs. How? If vertically slice the CNN, for example, calculate loss in gpu:0, convolution gradient part in gpu:1, validation in gpu:2. These are sequential operations, how it can speed up? Is it because pipelined if slice the CNN operation horizontally?

Comment: How (what is best way) to divide CNN training calculation into parallel pieces to run on multiple GPUs, so that it trains faster? The Tensorflow sample provided suggests 'vertical' slice calculation into different GPUs. As these calculation is dependent, how it could be faster, even on different GPUs?

Comment: Distribute dependent tasks into different GPUs does not really speed up the training process. For a CNN, how to figure out what task is parallel and can be divided into different GPUs? Even it exists, you have to restructure your code? The obvious parallel task is batch data. For example, if 1 epoch has 3 batches. It can be run on 3 GPUs, and weight updates sequence does not really matter as long as it's critical section resource. This way, no need to change model code much. Like to hear more comments.

Comment: You talked about dependent tasks, in parallel computing through GPU there is a concept of work group, a work group shares the private memory of a GPU to access the variable or values to work with, there are synchronization issues if you want different work groups to access the same variable or data in the private memory, so it would be a very difficult task to assign different work groups within the three GPU's the same data.

Comment: You will have to analyze your data to find out the slices which are not dependent on each other and give that data to GPU's for processing, You can either divide the data into parts for processing or assign the layers of CNN to be computed by the  GPU's respectively. But if you want to run all the GPU's and processing run simultaneously, you will have to divide the processing and data in a way that they are not dependent on each other. Otherwise it will effect your results due to synchronization problems.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thank you for your comments. I studied little more and realized https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn should work for me now. Single PC with 3 GPUs is my configuration.  My model fits in 1 CPU (32GB memory). I can distribute loss+gradient propagation into 3 GPUs. 3 GPUs shares same model on CPU. In such configuration, code modification is minimum. Tensorflow can also be configured into distributed (different PCs) training, which may also be used in my case, but it's little more complicated to configure. This is not what I am looking for now.

Comment: Yes, actually the process which is iterating is put in to the GPU for processing, what tensorflow will do that your CPU will send the process to your GPU's which are iterating and will get the results back in the CPU and will perform the simple actions required on the results provided by the GPU's and yes it will become much complex if you use the distributed approach.